# apply lambda function error for date issue

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply, series

I am trying to extract month from the below join_date. below is the structure of the emp table. and i am getting an error while performing the below code:

```
emp['join_mth']=emp['join_date'].apply(lambda x:x[:7])

emp_id emp_name account_id join_date
1       rob     121         2019-01-01
2       sam     122         2019-02-02
3       mike    123         2019-03-03
4       tom     124         2019-04-04 

type(emp['join_date'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

emp.dtypes
emp_id          object
emp_name        object  
account_id      object
join_date       object
dtype:object

fail to excute line - 10: emp['join_mth']=emp['join_date'].apply(lambda x:x[:7])
```

Below is the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 39, in <module>
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "<stdin>", line 39, in <lambda>
TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 70, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'last_value'
```

Comment: read your error carefully it says `'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable` so your 'join_date' is of dtype datetime.date so use `emp['join_date'].astype(str).str[:7]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read your error carefully it says: "'datetime.date' object is not subscriptable" so your `'join_date'` is of dtype `datetime.date` so use typecast it to string first:

```
emp['join_mth']=emp['join_date'].astype(str).str[:7]
#OR
emp['join_mth']=emp['join_date'].astype(str).apply(lambda x:x[:7])
```

OR

Since it's of type `datetime.date` so you can also use:

```
emp['join_date']=[x.strftime("%Y-%m") for x in emp['join_date']]
#OR
emp['join_mth']=emp['join_date'].map(lambda x:x.strftime("%Y-%m"))
```

**OR**

If you only want to extract **month** then use:

```
emp['join_date']=[x.strftime("%m") for x in emp['join_date']]
#emp['join_date'].apply(lambda x:x.strftime("%m"))
#OR(use above code for string format and below for int format)
emp['join_date']=[x.month for x in emp['join_date']]
#emp['join_date'].map(lambda x:x.month)
```

Answer (score 0):

You column is not a string but a datetime object, use the relevant method [`pandas.Series.dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), which will enable you to get the month number directly:

```
emp['join_date'].dt.month
```

Take advantage of this method as you won't need to handle double digits months.